# Gedit not working as root in kali VMware

Tags: linux, vmware, kali-linux

Hi im new to working with Linux , And im taking a Kali Course and im having a issue. So When im logged into Kali ( default user ) i can use Gedit when in Kali but it wont let save to the directory because i lack the permission or authorization (prob because i made new it in root)  . , But When im logged into Root, when i try to launch gedit it keeps hitting me with a Error . It says  Gedit:28839 : Gtk-Warning **: cannot open display. Is this a Root only thing ? And how can i fix this?

Im running Kali 2022.3 On VmWare codename Kali-rolling

Comment: Why are you logging in as root? Just use `sudo`. And ask your teachers before random people on the internet, of course.

Comment: If you are new to Linux, then please use another distro. Kali is built for advanced users only. If this is part of a course, then find another course for beginners. Kali is also not named after the Hindu god.

Comment: After you install gedit, run sudo gedit.  You can edit and save in your user folder. No errors, nothing special. It just works.  I tried it here on my own Kali VM

Comment: Also a much smoother text editor in Kali is Mousepad.  Comes built into Kali and works better than Gedit (my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

First, run this command:
`xhosts +`

This allows users to run apps as themselves in an X environment logged in as another user.

You can specify specific users as well, man xhosts for more details.

After that, make sure your DISPLAY variable is setup.  It should work.  I do it all the time.

Comment: You do know that using `xhost +` allows anybody on the network to attach to your display, capturing all outputs and keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `export VISUAL=$(which gedit)` to set Gedit as your visual editor. You have to do this only once per terminal.
2. To edit a file use `sudo -e path/to/file` or `sudoedit path/to/file`. This command will:

   - Create an editable copy of the file
   - Launch editor with that file open
   - Copy new content back into the original file as root

This way you avoid launching Gedit as root altogether, while still achieving your goal.

If you want the change to `VISUAL` to be persistent, put it in your `.bashrc`.